# Mongoose Bulkwrite: Triggers for nModified

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am doing a bulkwrite on a Collection, where no values are changed on the document. Still mongoose is returning:

```
     BulkWriteResult {
        result:
         { ok: 1,
           writeErrors: [],
           writeConcernErrors: [],
           insertedIds: [],
           nInserted: 0,
           nUpserted: 0,
           nMatched: 1,
           nModified: 1,
           nRemoved: 0,
           upserted: [] },
        insertedCount: 0,
        matchedCount: 1,
        modifiedCount: 1,
        deletedCount: 0,
        upsertedCount: 0,
        upsertedIds: {},
        insertedIds: {},
        n: 0 }
```

instead of the expected

```
     BulkWriteResult {
        result:
         { ok: 1,
           writeErrors: [],
           writeConcernErrors: [],
           insertedIds: [],
           nInserted: 0,
           nUpserted: 0,
           nMatched: 1,
           nModified: 1,
           nRemoved: 0,
           upserted: [] },
        insertedCount: 0,
        matchedCount: 1,
        modifiedCount: 0,
        deletedCount: 0,
        upsertedCount: 0,
        upsertedIds: {},
        insertedIds: {},
        n: 0 }
```

What are the criteria, for Mongoose to count a document as modified? Might this be due to the updatedAt and createdAt fields? Can I somehow exclude those two fields from being counted as modified, if this is the case?

Comment: Do you even want `updatedAt` to update if the document does not change?

Comment: No, not really, but not sure how I could prevent this